# SharedPreferences read vs write speed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to store some `String` I get from the server. Assume this happens each 30 seconds, but it almost always the same `String`, it changes, lets say, once a day. 
My question is what will the best practice:

1. Read each time the `String` from the `SharedPreferences`, compare it to the `String` arrived and write to `SharedPreferences` only if they are not equal (happens 1:3000)
2. Each arrived `String` just written to the `SharedPreferences`, overriding stored value.

What will be the more correct way in the context of synchronization and time?

Comment: Why would you want to read the `String` out of you pref every time? Just store if after the first access and compare that.

Comment: Store it where? The application may be closed in the middle and reopened.

Comment: store it in a static field somewhere and read from shared preferences only if it's null...?

Comment: @lelloman that's an improvement, but again, if it is null, what is the best practice ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get the problem, you can access the variable as you would with a singleton so that you will read from shared preferences only once per application "life"

Comment: in the very simple words, what takes less time - to read from SP or to write to it?

Comment: Try both and compare battery lifes. İ assume that fisrt way might use less energy

Comment: @EmreAktürk thanks, but that is exactly the point - I posted the question in hope that someone did the experiment like this ))))

Comment: Btw you dont need to worry about right time. You can call editor.apply() method that saves your data async. İt wont effect your performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you create both functions and compare their time execution, for example, perform 1000 Operations and compare their results. 
You can create functions like:

```
    public static long readAndCompare() {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //1000 read and compare operations
    long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long readAndCompareExcutionTime = endtime - startTime;
    return readAndCompareExcutionTime;
}


public static long OverrideSharedPreferenceValue() {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //1000 Override operations
    long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long OverrideExcutionTime = endtime - startTime;
    return OverrideExcutionTime;
}
```

and compare the return of `readAndCompare()` and `OverrideSharedPreferenceValue()`